# Laptop gets stuck after closing lid on after upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: laptop, lenovo, 19.10

I just installed Ubuntu 19.10, and now when I close my laptop's lid and then open it again the system won't start back up, however the screen does turn on and an underscore symbol appears in the upper left corner. I have to then restart the computer.

This worked perfectly fine before (on 19.04). I would like my computer to go into suspend automatically when I close the lid, I would rather downgrade than lose this ability.

My computer is a Lenovo Legion Y540. The processor is an Intel i7-9750H and the graphics is NVidia GeForce RTX 2060.

Not sure if this is relevant, but I found some similar issues that had something to do with the boot loader, and when I upgraded I got a warning saying that my version of GRUB had been locally modified (!). I selected the option to replace it with the package maintainer's version.

Does anyone know of a fix for this?

Comment: I am having pretty much the same issue. Any luck finding a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Eventually this stopped happening for me and this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195477/login-screen-takes-a-long-time-to-open-after-suspend started happening instead. It is a very similar problem, so that solution might work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is the same problem but since i've upgraded to Xubuntu 19.10 when I closed and open my laptop lid the graphical window became non-responsive. I could see the mouse cursor moving otherwise the screen is frozen.

Removing the screensaver service from the startup seems to have solved the problem. Hope it helps on regular Ubuntu too.

Answer (score -1):

8-9 months ago, I had a huge crash (non-recoverable thing even though there were tons of articles on "how-to-fix-it" - non of them worked) caused by the usage of the free graphics drivers (nvidia card).

Reinstalled ubuntu 19.4, specifically used the proprietary ones and it worked.

Recently (end-of-April 2020) there was a big-ish update. After this, my laptop stopped suspending when I was closing the lid. The fan was blowing like crazy until the battery was drained.

I've seen lots of people  with similar problems around video-card drivers, so I decided to restore them to the open-source version. Et voila: it works like a charm. Hopefully, that crash that made me reinstall the OS will not reappear.

Don't have to approve this as an "accepted answer" - unless it really worked for you - because, to be honest, I cannot explain it and give more details on whys and hows. I am just dropping this here so it can help other poor soul going through the same pain as I did and have less gray hair. ;-)

HTH.

Comment: So what is the advice? Install the EoL 19.04 release?

Comment: Read from left-to-right, top-to-bottom: "Reinstalled ubuntu 19.4, ___specifically used the proprietary ones___ and it worked."

Comment: What is 19.4? If it is 19.04, then It has reached its end of life. So what is the point of posting this

Comment: The advice is to switch to the proprietary graphics drivers. You can do this in Software & Updates > Additional Drivers. Doing this might have been the reason that this stopped happening for me.